# AVCaptureStillImageOutput connection withType returns nil connection

Tags: ios, swift, ipad

I'm using the `AVCaptureStillImageOutput` to capture a photo on iOS.
To capture the photo I'm calling `captureStillImageAsynchronously`.
This requires a connection so I use:

`let connection = stillImageOutput.connection(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)`

However on certain devices namely **iPad 2** on **iOS 9.3.5** I see that the connection returned is nil.

I also tried iterating through all connections using:

`stillImageOutput.connections`

This shows there are no connections available.

Has anyone else encountered this issue? Is there another better way to obtain the connection? I realize I'm using a deprecated class however the new method is not available on iOS 9 and we still need to support this platform. BTW the camera app itself appears to work just fine on this device.

Also just noticed that `canAddInput` on `AVCaptureSession` is returning false.

The input is obtained as follows:

```
guard let captureDevices = AVCaptureDevice.devices(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo) as? [AVCaptureDevice],
      let captureDevice = captureDevices.first(where: { $0.position == .back }),
      let captureDeviceInput = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice) else {
                return
        }
```

Comment: In my case stillImageOutput.connections was nil because i was allocating AVCaptureSession and AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer twice, so just added check whether session == nil  then only do [[AVCaptureStillImageOutput alloc] init] and all stillImageOutput preset